# How to use upgrader_process_complete hook in WordPress to check for spcific plugin update

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use `upgrader_process_complete` hook to check if only a specific plugin is updated?

I want to run a function every time a certain plugin is updated, for example warn the user about the changes or updating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for it you can use this code:

```
/**
 * This function runs when WordPress completes its upgrade process
 * It iterates through each plugin updated to see if ours is included
 * @param $upgrader_object Array
 * @param $options Array
 */
function wp_upe_upgrade_completed( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
 // The path to our plugin's main file
 $our_plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
 // If an update has taken place and the updated type is plugins and the plugins element exists
 if( $options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' && isset( $options['plugins'] ) ) {
  // Iterate through the plugins being updated and check if ours is there
  foreach( $options['plugins'] as $plugin ) {
   if( $plugin == $our_plugin ) {
    // Your action if it is your plugin

   }
  }
 }
}
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'wp_upe_upgrade_completed', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: is there a way to test this in development?

Comment: @RainMan put this code into functions.php file of your template and edit code to detect plugin that you want after its update

Comment: I mean is there a way to trigger this hook for testing without publishing the plugin for update?

Comment: @RainMan yes, you need to trigger it or some another plugin to update

Comment: @RainMan can you please update me about result of testing?

Comment: @RainMan there is no way (that I know) to ask WP to trigger a "fake" upgrade. if you just wanna test the logic of your own hook, just call `wp_upe_upgrade_completed` yourself with a dummy `$options` variable. if you want to actually test the action trigger, either test it on a different plugin that you can afford to upgrade or setup a dev clone of your site.