# Need to call another function while wordpress plugin upgrader process

Tags: wordpress

Is there any possibility to call another function inside the upgrader_process_complete hook in wordpress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use upgrader\_process\_complete hook in WordPress to check for spcific plugin update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019930/how-to-use-upgrader-process-complete-hook-in-wordpress-to-check-for-spcific-plug)